# Is it possible to deactivate caching Rules in htacces by IP matching?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to deactivate caching Rules like mod_expires.c, mod_headers.c in htaccess by IP matching like < FilesMatch > or < IfModule >?

I did not find any possible solution so far. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deactivate caching you can use the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A1
Header append Cache-Control must-revalidate
```

Just make sure you place it at the top of your `.htaccess` file and clear your cache upon entering it. From that point forward it will also ask the cache to re-validate.

Comment: I just saw you wanted this to be by IP matching. You can do that, but you would require an IF statement to achieve that... You could potentially use `RewriteCond`.. something like `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} xx.x.x.x [NC]` But, I'm not certain that would work with the above.